# PHP with MS sql server

Tags: php, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to get the user's hashed password from my database but this function doesn't seem to return if it's valid or not, I feel like there's something wrong with assigning `$hashedPass` to the `sqlsrv_prepare` function. What's the proper way to do it if I'm doing it wrong?

```
function validate($conn, $username, $password)

{ 
    $isValid = false;

    $sql = "SELECT UserPassword 
            FROM dbo.Users(FullName,Username,UserPassword,Email,PhoneNumber) 
            WHERE Username = ?";
    $hashedPass = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$username));

    sqlsrv_execute($hashedPass);
    sqlsrv_fetch($hashedPass);
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($hashedPass);


    if(crypt($password, $hashedPass) == $hashedPass)
        $isValid = true;

    return $isValid;
}
```

Comment: The call to crypt is wrong, take a look at the examples in http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php. Much better, don't use crypt at all, use password_hash and password_verify, they take care of the details for you.

Comment: Oh and, uh, you never got the return from your fetch so you're just hashing your prepared statement.

Comment: I'll modify it, and my question is about the select statement is it right or wrong ?

Comment: the select is fine, but take a look at the sqlsrv_ docs, you basically never get the result out of the db. sql_prepare doesn't get things out of the db, it makes a sql statement for the db to run. you then run that prepared statement but never do anything with the result. don't call that 'hashedPass' because it isn't and i think it's confusing both you and potential readers of your code :)